# How to get rid of "recovered documents" and "Reopen closed PDFs" pop-up messages?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, acrobat-pro-dc

When I open Adobe Acrobat Pro DC, it often shows me either or both of these two pop-up messages:

> Adobe Acrobat has recovered one or more documents that were not saved properly before Acrobat was shut down. Click Yes to open the recovered documents. If you click No, your changes will be lost.

[image]

And

> Reopen closed PDFs // Your last Acrobat session ended abruptly. Click Restore to reopen the PDFs from the last session.

I'm using Microsoft Windows 11 Home Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621 and

[image]

---

As per [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/how-to-stop-quot-reopen-closed-pdfs-quot-message/td-p/11073977) and [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/asking-how-to-stop-the-quot-reopen-closed-pdfs-quot-message-from-appearing/m-p/10519995), **I've already done all of the following** but the problem still persists:

1. Regedit > ... > SessionRestorePromptAbnormalExit
2. Uncheck "Open PDFs from last session on Acrobat launch"

[image]

3. Uncheck "Restore last view settings when reopening documents"

[image]

4. Uncheck "Show me messages when I launch Adobe Acrobat"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I tried all the solutions you reproduced without success, on a similar platform (Windows 11, Acrobat Reader 2023.006.20320 64-bit).

Following the first link you put in your post:

(https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/how-to-stop-quot-reopen-closed-pdfs-quot-message/td-p/11073977), the second answer (from DevilDoc325)  is the only solution that has ever worked for me, and judging from your post may not be one you tried.

I do have a simple single user (me) on a personal computer use case, so obviously some people may have reasons not to take this permissions based approach. All I can say is it fixes it for me under my use case.

Recently the registry entries seem to have been moved a little by Adobe and the fix stopped working as described, but finding the SessionManagement key in its new (for me) location under 'Adobe Acrobat' rather than 'Adobe Reader' and following the same instruction seems to still fix it sofar.